# Chaining nested promises in the loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

There is a controller that gets say countries and their cities using the service which uses `$http.get()` to fetch data from the server. Both the countries and the cities are json arrays.

**Current implementation**

service

```
service.getCountries = function() {
    return $http.get('url');
}

service.getCities = function(country) {
    return $http.get('url' + country);
}
```

controller

```
        var getCountries = function () {
            service.getCountries()
                .success(function (countries) {
                    angular.forEach(countries, function (country) {
                        // process country
                        getCities(country);
                    });
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert('failed to load countries');
                });
        };

        var getCities = function (country) {
            service.getCities(country)
                .success(function (cities) {
                    angular.forEach(cities, function (city) {
                        // process city
                    });
                })
                .error(function () {
                    alert('failed to load cities of ' + country);
                });
        };

        var doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded = function () {
            // do
        }

        getCountries();
        doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded();
```

I want to chain the fetching of countries and cities so that `doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded()` is processed as a last chain.
How this code can be converted to promise chaining with proper error handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to execute a number of promises in parallel, you need `$q.all`, and in order to chain actions, you need to return your promises:

```
var getCountries = function () {
     return service.getCountries()
         .then(function (result) {
             return $q.all(result.data.map(getCities));
         }).catch(function (result) {
             var message = 'failed to load countries';
             console.log(message);
             throw new Error(message);
         });
};

var getCities = function (country) {
     return service.getCities(country)
         .then(function (result) {
             angular.forEach(result.data, function (city) {
                 // process city
             });
         }).catch(function () {
             var message = 'failed to load cities of ' + country;
             console.log(message);
             throw new Error(message);
         });    
};

var doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded = function () {
      // do
};

getCountries().then(doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded);
```

Comment: Why `throw new Error(message)` is needed?

Comment: That's needed in order for `getCountries` to know that one of the `getCities` operations failed. For that matter, I'd say it makes sense to throw an error in the `getCountries` function's `catch` too.

Comment: Well, bit more questions: 1) the catch is used to handle defer.reject() afaik. Can the catch also handle "throw new Error()" too? 2) Is there advantage using q's then/catch over http's success/error in above code?

Comment: @UlukBiy 1) Yes, a thrown error inside a `.then()` or `.catch()` handler will be turned into a rejected promise. 2) Yes, it is necessary here. If you used `.success()` and `.error()` instead, then the value returned from `getCountries()` would be the _original_ `service.getCountries()` promise instead of one transformed through the `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers.

Comment: Thank you for answers! So you mean the promises that the `success()` returned and the `then()` returned are different.

Comment: @UlukBiy Yes, `success()` returns the promise it was called on and `then()` returns a new promise.

Answer (score 1):

Return the result of the `service.getCountries` call (which is a promise) and chain the result with `then` and `catch`. In the former's callback function call `doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded` and in the latter's handle any errors.

```
var getCountries = function () {
   return service.getCountries()
      .then(function (countries) {
        ....
};

getCountries()
   .then(function(countries){
       doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded(countries);
   }
   .catch(error){
       //handle errors
   }
```

Comment: Actually service returns the promise itself rather than its result (see edit). Is there need to wait for cities to be loaded between getCountries and doAfterCountriesAndCitiesLoaded?

Comment: Yes but you need to return the promise returned from the service and then await its resolving using the chained `then`. As for the cities you could use `$q.all` and resolve when all are processed. Makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is quite right: I don't think `success` returns a promise, which means you can't call `then` on its return value to process it further. However, you can just call the standard `then` function directly on the promise returned by `$http` to process the results.

Comment: @MichalCharemza You're right, it needs to be `then` and not `success`, I'll edit my response.

Comment: @MichalCharemza `.success()` returns the promise it was called on, to allow chaining. It doesn't provide a way to transform the result the way `.then()` does.